# Convert number string with commas and negative values to float [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert negative value strings and strings with commas to float
df. But I am struggling to do both operations at the same time

```
customer_id  Revenue
332          1,293.00
293          -485
4284         1,373.80
284          -327
```

Output_df

```
332          1293.00
293          485
4284         1373.80
284          327
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting pandas Dataframe to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000347/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to numeric and then take the absolute value:

```py
df["Revenue"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Revenue"]).abs()
```

If the above doesn't work, then try:

```py
df["Revenue"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Revenue"].str.strip().str.replace(",", "")).abs()
```

Here I first make a call to `str.strip()` to remove any whitespace in your float.  Then, I remove commas using `str.replace()`.

Comment: I get the following error: ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,373.80" at position 3

Comment: @user12625679 Then try stripping off commas first before converting to float.

Comment: I get this error now: ValueError: Unable to parse string " -   " . The problem is that I cannot convert negative string and comma strings to numeric at the same time

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  It's possible to convert a negative float to a string, and vice-versa.

Comment: I've been struggling with this error for a while - I either get the unable to parse string "1,3737.80" error or converting "-" to numeric error

Comment: Question: Is that minus sign really a minus sign, and not an em-dash or en-dash (or something else)?

Comment: I see that the sign is: ' -   '

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does using `.str.replace()` help?

```py
df["Revenue"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Revenue"].str.replace(',','').abs()
```

If you are getting the DataFrame from a csv file, you can use the following at import to address the commas, and then deal with the `-` later:

```py
df.read_csv ('foo.​csv', thousands=',')
df["Revenue"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Revenue"]).abs()
```

Comment: Unintended duplicate of an edit someone else made to their answer at the same time I was answering.

Comment: No worries.  Neither of our answers appears to be working `:-)`